# Printing a protocol(list with dicts)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

Im having a list, called protocol filled with player objects in Yatzy. Every object is an dictionary containing the moments(like full house) and the value(ex. 20).

I would like to print the protocol but don´t now how to formulate the code.

I would like it to look something like this:

One line with the player names
Ones one line for the points for every player on the "ones" moment

and so on.

I´ve tried this so far(protokoll=protocol, momentlist= a list with all moments(ones, twos and so on):

```
def Utskrift(protokoll, momentlist):

    for key in momentlist:
        print ("%-20s" % key)
        for deltagare in protokoll:
            print (deltagare.protokoll[key], "\t",)
```

Doesn't work, the error message says something about the class Spelare, which I use to make every player.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram.py", line 160, in <module>
    meny()
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram.py", line 139, in meny
    Utskrift(protokoll, momentlist)
  File "/Users/Mans/Desktop/P-Uppgift/Yatzy_huvudprogram.py", line 93, in Utskrift
    print (deltagare.protokoll[key], "\t",)
AttributeError: 'Spelare' object has no attribute 'protokoll'
```

The thing is that when I use

for player in protokoll

print(player) 
it works without error(though it didn't print as I want).

Does the function Uskrift looks right?

Thanks for helping

Comment: _"the error message says something about the class Spelare"_. That probably means there's something wrong with your Spelare class, then. We can't give much more advice than that, since we don't know what the class or the error look like.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Ive updated the info. Thing thing is that when I use a simpler printing function it works without error.

What do you think about my function Utskrift?

Comment: You might get that error if your `Spelare` class has no `self.protokoll` attribute. What attributes _does_ your Spelare class have?

Comment: Ok. I´ve updated the info with my class Spelare.

Answer (score 0):

```
        print (deltagare.protokoll[key], "\t",)
```

Spelare does not have a `protokoll` attribute. If you're trying to access the Spelare's OrderedDict object, you should use its name, `moment`.

```
        print (deltagare.moment[key], "\t",)
```

Comment: Sweet Kevin, thank you so much!
One last thing, I´ve made your suggested change and it´s printing
the key and value on different rows.
Do you know how to do if I would like to print the key and its value on the same row?

?

Comment: Try deleting the first `print` and modifying the second one to `print ("%-20s" % key, deltagare.protokoll[key], "\t",)`

Comment: Yes! Thanks SO much for your time, have really helped my a lot! Thanks and have a nice day!